# If I get a second Xbox One, will the Destiny expansions transfer?

Tags: destiny, xbox-one

So I am but a second Xbox one for my bedroom but I am not sure if I re-buy destiny that the season pass would transfer. (But also I bought the disc version previously, not sure if that makes a difference). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Aren't they registered on the same account?

Answer (score 5):

If you log in with the same Xbox Live account on both Xboxes, then you will be able to use the Destiny DLC on both. If you want to play co-op and use both Xboxes at the same time, then it won't work because your account can only be logged in to one Xbox at a time. Unless whomever you're playing with has also bought the Destiny DLC, they will need to purchase it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you get a second Xbox one, as long as you login to the same account you can download the expansion pass and DLC.

I hope this helped